# How do I configure a .net catchall route to show home controller's index for JavaScript push state routes?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to set up an Angular SPA application using .net WebApi as my backend. I want to use push state for my routing and need to know how I to create a route that will send the user to HomeController's Index function if the route isn't found.

What is the best way to accomplish this?